# List Enterprise Wiki pages from subsite

Tags: 2013

I currently have a SP2013 Team Site with a Wiki Library. The Team Site has a Web Part on the front page that lists all the pages in the Wiki library.

Now I want to upgrade to an Enterprise Wiki subsite. How can I insert a Web Part  on the parent Team Site that lists the Enterprise Wiki subsite pages? It would make it so much easier visitors to browse the Enterprise Wiki pages.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution posted on a blog by David Bishop on [blog.cloudbusiness.com](http://blog.cloudbusiness.com/the-company/blog-and-news/displaying-sharepoint-online-2013-lists-to-parent-or-sub-sites).
 Although there were quite a few other similar posts, they were often solutions that worked in SharePoint 2010 but not in SharePoint 2013.

This solution involves using SharePoint Designer to save the web part to the Site Gallery to make it available to all sites. Basically the process is:

- Open SharePoint Designer
- Access the view you wish to replicate in other sites
- Insert a Data View
- Save the Web Part to the Site Gallery and give it a name
- Go back to the site into which you wish to insert the web part
- Insert the new Site Gallery Web Part which appears as a "Miscellaneous" Web Part

This is a very brief overview, but the article referenced above has a full step-by-step with screen shots.